# Wordpress - Set Sender - Prevent "Via default@domain.com"

Tags: wordpress, email

I have been having trouble with the emails I send from my wordpress site.  Everything comes from "info@mydomain.co.za via default@hostingprovider.net"

The via part looks really untidy and unprofessional.  From past experience I know that this has to do with the Sender not being set.  I searched for the setting to change this in Wordpress but to no avail.  It seems that it can not be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can automatically set the sender by adding this code to functions.php (or putting it in a plugin):

```
  # set the sender after PHP builds the phpmailer object during a wp_mail call
  add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_init' );
  function my_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From;
  }
```

This has the same effect as Talon's answer, but avoids editing core Wordpress files.  This way the change survives a Wordpress upgrade.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of searching I managed to find the bit of code that needs to be changed.

Open the file:
/wp-includes/pluggable.php

Find the lines that look like this:

```
// Plugin authors can override the potentially troublesome default
$phpmailer->From     = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from'     , $from_email );
$phpmailer->FromName = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from_name', $from_name  );
```

And add the following:

```
$phpmailer->Sender   = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from'     , $from_email );
```

So it should now look like this:

```
// Plugin authors can override the potentially troublesome default
$phpmailer->From     = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from'     , $from_email );
$phpmailer->FromName = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from_name', $from_name  );
$phpmailer->Sender   = apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from'     , $from_email );
```

This will prevent the "via unwanted@host.net" and will not just come from you.

**BEWARE:**
This may cause spam issues IF your email address is different from your domain name.
ie:

```
BAD: noreply@example.com and your website is www.mysite.com
GOOD: noreply@mysite.com and your website is www.mysite.com
```

I hope this saves someone out there an hour or 2 like I just wasted.